# restMockMvc - Expected: a collection containing <1.0F> but: was <1.0>

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit5

I have a problem when I run a test on a rest endpoint:

java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$.[*].montant"

Expected: a collection containing <1.0F>
but: was <1.0>

Expected :a collection containing <1.0F>
Actual   :<1.0>

the code is:

```
restMockMvc.perform(get("/api/{id}", dommage.getId()))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[*].montant").value(hasItem(dommage.getMontant())));
```

The test failed because the value doesn't match but how can I format the json result to match with a Float or test is with the current output?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Just to clarify, the response of API is "1.0" and you expect that will be "1.0F"? I asked because is the attribute is a number is okay that the answer is 1.0

Comment: It's correct, the API response is 1.0 but the test expects 1.0F so it failed.

Comment: can you show the return type of `getMontant()` method ?

Comment: I use lombok annotation for the getter/setter but the property is:    
private Float montant

Comment: Could you try something like this "new DecimalFormat("#.##").format(dommage.getMontant())" in "hasItem" method

Comment: Sure, the result is "Expected: a collection containing "1"
     but: was <1.0>".

Comment: My mistake, the correct expression is "new DecimalFormat(""#.0")format(dommage.getMontant())"

Comment: if I change the pattern to new DecimalFormat("#.0"), the result is "Expected: a collection containing "1.0"
     but: was <1.0>"

Comment: Some sites recomend the not use "value" to check, instead suggest something like this jsonPath("$.[*].montant", hasItem(new DecimalFormat(""#.0")format(dommage.getMontant()))

Comment: Indeed but I tried this but same result; .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[*].montant", hasItem(new DecimalFormat("#.0").format(dommage.getMontant()))));

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finaly found how deal with this problem.

Before the test I modified the default JsonProvider from JsonSmartJsonProvider (by default) to JacksonJsonProvider.

I did it with this piece of code during the test init:

```
     Configuration.setDefaults(new Configuration.Defaults() {

        private final JsonProvider jsonProvider = new JacksonJsonProvider();
        private final MappingProvider mappingProvider = new JacksonMappingProvider();

        @Override
        public JsonProvider jsonProvider() {
            return jsonProvider;
        }

        @Override
        public MappingProvider mappingProvider() {
            return mappingProvider;
        }

        @Override
        public Set<Option> options() {
            return EnumSet.noneOf(Option.class);
        }
    });
```

In addition of this, I modified my test like this:

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.[*].montant", Float.class).value(hasItem(dommage.getMontant().doubleValue())));
```

I used the double value because the expected value is 1.0F and the json result is 1.0.